# SLRequest twitter access now requires SSL

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, slrequest

```
-(void) vSLRequest:(SLRequest*) SLRequest1 WithHandler:(NSString *) errorTitle andD1: (NSString *) errorDescription FP1:(NSString *) errorParse FP2:(NSString *) errorParseDesc ifSuccess:(void(^)(NSDictionary * resp))succesBlock
{
    [self vSuspendAndHaltThisThreadTillUnsuspendedWhileDoing:^{
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [SLRequest1 performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                if(error != nil) {
                    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
                        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:errorTitle message:errorDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
                    }];
                }
```

Now the response data contains the following:

```
(lldb) po resp
{
    errors =     (
                {
            code = 92;
            message = "SSL is required";
        }
    );
}
```

Okay so, twitter now requires SSL. https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239 is the discussion.

How should I change my code?

Answer (score 0):

`SLRequest` has an `account` property. You need to set this to the user's twitter account (which is an `ACAccount` object you get from the `ACAccountStore` class.

If you set this, the connection is authenticated and OAuth is performed for you.

So, you need to do the following:

- Create an `ACAccountStore` object
- Request access to twitter accounts using `requestAccessToAccountsWithType:...`
- Once access is granted, get the `ACAccount` object from the account store
- Add this to your `SLRequest` object.

Answer (score 0):

I did get the same error when I used url `NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"];`

But I solved that error by changing url to this :`NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"];`

-> The error `message = "SSL is required"` says that "SSL requirement will be enforced on all api.twitter.com URLs, including all steps of OAuth and all REST API resources."
which means that now onwards we have to use "https://" instead of "http://" we were using previously.

Below is whole the code which will help you to understand better:

```
- (void) postTweet
{
    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType: accountType
                                     options: nil
                                  completion: ^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
    {
        if (granted == YES){

            // Get account and communicate with Twitter API
            NSLog(@"Access Granted");

            NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account
                                        accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) {

                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];

                NSDictionary *message = @{@"status": @"My First Twitter post from iOS 7"};

                NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"];

                SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                            requestMethod: SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                                      URL: requestURL
                                                               parameters: message];

                postRequest.account = twitterAccount;

                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                 {
                    NSLog(@"Twitter HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
                    NSLog(@"Twitter ResponseData = %@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error]);
                 }];
            }
        }
        else {

            NSLog(@"Access Not Granted");
        }
    }];
}
```